# bootstrap 3 toggle button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Yes i know this question has been asked previously on Stackoverflow millions of time,i looked over them but still unable to find what's wrong.Any help would be appreciated,thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>front page</title>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">     <!--Main menu starts-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any error on console? try loading scripts before `</body>` tag instead of header.

Comment: yes i have a error in console,Script error.So i should always use script tag just before the ending of body tag ?

Comment: yes, it's good practice to load script before the end of body tag.

Comment: @azs06 thank you, i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery file should be loaded first in order to achieve that.

So it should be like this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```